# Cannot convert parameter from WCHAR[100] to WCHAR**

Tags: c++, wchar

I have a method expecting WCHAR**, i need to get some data back from this method. I am declaring an array WCHAR[100] and passing it to the function. The compiler throws this error:

```
WCHAR result[100];
UINT i;
hr = SomeFunc(handle, &i, result);
```

error C2664: 'XXXX' : cannot convert parameter 3 from 'WCHAR [100]' to 'WCHAR **'

Comment: Shoudn't it be `WCHAR* result; fn(&result);` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally speaking, if a function takes a pointer to a pointer (`WCHAR**` in this case) then it will allocate its own memory and set the pointed-to pointer to that memory. The documentation of `SomeFunc` should describe if this is indeed what happens.

If that is the case, then you would likely need something like:

```
WCHAR* result = NULL;
UINT i;
hr = SomeFunc(handle, &i, &result);
```

And then make use of `result` if successful.

Of course, in that case you also most likely need to worry about deallocating the memory that `result` was set to point to. The documentation of `SomeFunc` should explicitly say what's necessary to do that as well.

Comment: and if SomeFunc's documentation does not provide you that info, throw something heavy in the general direction of the developer :). If it is a "standard" function, ie stdlib/string etc .. you should be good to expect valid pointer, if SomeFunc succeeds, and NULL if not.